# Search engines (SEO): do they see information if it appended with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, seo, search-engine

I mean such situation. When page loads (before `$(document).ready` state):

```
$("head").append("<title>Some title here</title>");
```

So, do they see that `title`? Very interesting.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An aside - this is not how you should set a document title in js! Use document.title = 'something' instead

Comment: +1: That is an excellent point, Scott.

Answer (score 5):

No. Most (if not all) search engines do not process javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment yet, I have to write a new answer...

@Christopher Harris thats no exactly correct. At least google crawls JavaScript for links. But thats it. They wont parse JavaScript, because most people struggle to write it correct and the crawler is in hurry. ;-)

Comment: “Google crawls JavaScript for links” [citation needed]

Comment: @MathiasBynens e.g. they said it in [Googles Webmaster Central Blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/04/crawling-through-html-forms.html)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment yet either, so I too will write an answer...

@Christopher Harris and @netzaffin, Google does more than just crawl JavaScript for links. It parses it 'enough' to index content on your page that is added by JavaScript. It does not however index content that is added as the result of an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

this site http://ajax.rswebanalytics.com/seo-for-ajax/ is a good reference for most of javascript procedures like the  example.